# Archiving Custom Object in Swift - Extended

Tags: ios, swift, nscoding, user-preferences, nsarchiving

I am working on an iOS App on Swift 4.0. The app uses an 3rd party SDK where there is a model lets say,

```
class Customer: NSCopying, NSObject {

    var name: String!
    var age: Int!
    var address: Address!
}
```

At that point I have no control to modify any properties and signature for the model as its inside SDK. But I need to store the object in disk/user defaults and load when needed.

Is it possible? If it is then how can I do that?

Comment: Add extension to Customer and confirm Coadable protocol, will it not help ? Lemme know if I did not understood your question properly

Comment: You can't conform to Codable in an extension. You can't add the initializer @SandeepBhandari

Comment: Yes I cannot add Initializer as Sweeper mentioned @SandeepBhandari

Comment: @sazzad-hissain-khan : I was thinking of swizzeling the init

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) to convert the model object to JSON data:

```
extension Customer {
    func toJSON() -> JSON {
        return [
            "name": name
            "age": age
            "address": address.toJSON() // add a toJSON method the same way in an Address extension
        ]
    }

    static func fromJSON(_ json: JSON) -> Customer {
        let customer = Customer()
        customer.name = json["name"].string
        customer.age = json["age"].int
        customer.address = Address.fromJSON(json["address"]) // add a fromJSON method the same way
    }
}
```

Now you can do something like saving to `UserDefaults`

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(try! Customer().toJSON().rawData(), forKey: "my key")
let customer = Customer.fromJSON(JSON(data: UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "my key")!))
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Is there any other way? The model I am using is composed of many other models and depth is also more than 2/3, It would be tedious task if I need to extend all those peach of other models :(

Comment: Whichever way you use, I suspect that you must handle all the classes manually. You don't have to write an extension for every one. I mean, you can convert `Address` to JSON in `Customer.toJSON` without creating a new `Address` extension. Another way is to create `Codable` wrappers of their model classes.